# How to make TortoiseSVN show green on a folder if there is no change except ignore folders?

Tags: svn

I'm using TortoiseSVN to manage a visual studio solution. The solution consists of several projects. Since when compiling the solution will generate bin and obj folders which shouldn't be  versioned, I added these folders to ignore list. Now take project1 for example, I enter the project1 folder and can see bin and obj folder show an  ignored icon, other folders/files show a normal icon. But on the parent folder of project1, the status of project1 is modified because of ignore files changes. How can I make the the project1's status show normal? Since I  don't want to commit this modification to svn server --this change might be useless to other users.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the the project1's status show normal?

Nohow. When you change ignores, you change versioned property of folder - and because versioned properties are the same first-class citizens for SVN, as versioned files|folders, you get "modified" state for your tree